# How to validate muliple js file using JSHINT

Tags: node.js, jshint

I can validate the current file in jshint by below code

```
jshint filename.js
```

but i want to validate entire folder.

```
*for example i have in js folder*

  abc.js
  cde.js
  efg.js
```

Answer (score 1):

Per [cheatsheet-like post](https://salomvary.github.io/jshint-everywhere.html), you do.

```
jshint .
```